# PHP Warning: in_array() : Wrong datatype for second argument

Tags: php, arrays, function

NOTE: I realize this is old code, but I'm hoping to repair it to get by until we can move to a new system next year.

I'm getting these two recurring errors from the two lines of code below.

How do I fix these errors?

Errors:

> PHP Warning:  in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument line 120
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function add_viewed() on a non-object line 121

Lines of code causing errors:

```
if (!in_array($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id'], $items_ids_on_display)) {
  $viewed->add_viewed($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
}
```

Full Code of file below

```
if (((tep_session_is_registered('customer_id')) or (ENABLE_PAGE_CACHE == 'false')) and (!$spider_flag)){


//*******************************************************************************
  DEFINE('HIST_ROWS', 7);         // number of rows per column on display
  DEFINE('HIST_MAX_ROWS',7);     // max number of products on display
  DEFINE('HIST_MEM_TRIGGER', 1);  // number when memory threshold kicks in
//*******************************************************************************

  // register the array if not already done so
  if (tep_session_is_registered('viewed') && is_object($viewed)) {
  } else {
    tep_session_register('viewed');
    $viewed = new viewed_products;
    $viewed->reset();
  }

  // empty the array if requested by the user
      if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['action'])) {
        if ($HTTP_GET_VARS['action'] == 'viewed_remove') {
          $viewed->remove();
        }
     }


// start shift from line 106 to here
 $items_ids_on_display = array();
// end shift


  // display the box if we have history
  if ($viewed->count_viewed() > 0) { // displaying
  ?>

    <tr>
  <td class="prodRowDivide">
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
  <tr class="header">
    <td>
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <?php
      echo '<tr><td nowrap valign="center" class="prodRowHead" height="22">Recently Viewed Products:<br></td></tr>
      </table>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td valign="top"><table border="0" cellpadding="3" align="left"><tr>'; 
    $info_box_contents = array();
    //$info_box_contents[] = array('text' => 'Recently Viewed');
    //new infoBoxHeading($info_box_contents, false, false);

    $row = 0;
    $col = 0;
    /* get the products array from the class containing all viewed products */


    $items = $viewed->get_viewed_items();


    $index = 1;
    /* determine the first and last record we want to display*/
    $first = sizeof($items)- HIST_MAX_ROWS;
    $last  = sizeof($items)-1;
    if (($last+1) < HIST_MAX_ROWS) {$disp = ($last+1);} else {$disp = HIST_MAX_ROWS;}
    if ($first < 0) {$first = 0;}

    /* only fetch the info for products on display */

//    $items_ids_on_display = array();          // shift to line 67
    for ($i=$last, $n=$first; $i>=$n; $i--) {
        $viewed_query = tep_db_query("select pd.products_name,
                                             p.products_image_lrg
                                      from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p,
                                           " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd
                                      where p.products_id = '" . $items[$i] . "' and
                                            pd.language_id = '" . $languages_id . "' and
                                            pd.products_id = p.products_id");
        if ($viewed_info = tep_db_fetch_array($viewed_query)) {
         $items_on_display[$i] = array('id' => $items[$i],
                                     'name' => $viewed_info['products_name'],
                                     'image' => $viewed_info['products_image_lrg']);
         $items_ids_on_display[]= $items[$i];
        }
    }

    for ($i=$last, $n=$first; $i>=$n; $i--) {
        $currentPage = (int)($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
    if ($currentPage != $items[$i]) {
    echo '<td align="left" class="smallText"><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $items_on_display[$i]['id']) . '">'. tep_image_thumb(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $items_on_display[$i]['image'], $items_on_display[$i]['name'], '120', '120') . '</a></center></td>';
      $row ++;
      $index++;
      }
    }
    ?>

</tr></table></td></tr>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top"><?php echo tep_draw_separator('pixel_trans.gif', '100%', '5'); ?></td>
   </tr>

<?php

  }
 // general condition
}

  if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']) and ($HTTP_GET_VARS['action'] != 'viewed_remove')) {
    if (!in_array($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id'], $items_ids_on_display)) {
      $viewed->add_viewed($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
    }
} ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Put `$items_ids_on_display = array();` before the first `if` statement. Odds are it's not getting defined before you hit the `in_array()` call.

Comment: You can put like this if(is_array($items_ids_on_display)) {
if (!in_array($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id'], $items_ids_on_display)) {
  $viewed->add_viewed($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
}
}
else
   echo "the item list is not an array";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error:

> PHP Warning:  in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument line 120

You are passing a value that is **not** an array into `in_array`. You can [see from the docs that an array is explicitly required for the second argument.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) This is because if your first if-statement at the top of the code isn't valid, `$items_ids_on_display` is unset.

**"How do I fix this error?"**

Check for the existence of `$item_ids_on_display` before attempting to use it in `in_array`.

The line

```
$viewed->add_viewed($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
```

Is reportedly trying to use the value of `$viewed` as an object with a method of `add_viewed()`, where the value of `$viewed` is not actually an object (it is unset when the applicable if-statement isn't satisfied.)

**"How do I fix this error?"**

Like before, check for the existence of `$viewed` before trying to attempt to utilize it as an object.

Ignoring any other code review and focusing on the reported problems, your resulting code at the bottom should be:

```
if (isset($items_ids_on_display) && isset($viewed) && isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']) and ($HTTP_GET_VARS['action'] != 'viewed_remove')) {
    if (!in_array($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id'], $items_ids_on_display)) {
      $viewed->add_viewed($HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id']);
    }
}
```

### Final Note

You should be programming with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` set so you see PHP notices along with the PHP warnings and errors. They will give you more insight as to *why* the warnings and errors are happening.

Comment: Thank you for the code fix and the detailed explanation, much appreciated!